# Passing an overloaded member function to function template

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, template-meta-programming

I would like to have a function, that calls a given member function with the provides variadic input argument. I wrote something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>    

struct A {
    constexpr int show(int a, int b) const noexcept {return a + b;}
};

template <typename T, typename MemFn, typename ... Args>
int show(T && obj, MemFn Fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return (obj.*Fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr A a;
    return show(a, &A::show, 1, 2);
}
```

and it works just fine, as long as I only have one definition of `show` method in my struct. As soon as I add something like

```
struct A {
    constexpr int show(int a, int b) const noexcept {return a + b;}
    constexpr int show(int a) const noexcept {return a * 3;}
};
```

The compiler can not deduce the type of the member function and it really makes all the sense, but I was wondering if there is a workaround for this problem, like embedding the input arguments types in member function template or something?

Sample code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9KI-Co).

Comment: Do you want your function to only accept member functions with specific signature?

Comment: @r3musn0x yes, it has to be member function, I know I could fix it with lambdas

Comment: Your function `::show()` - if you invert the first two arguments is a specialized version of `std::invoke()` in case you want to use that instead. Just FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an annoyingly difficult problem, which continuously leads to language proposals in an attempt to address it ([P0119](https://wg21.link/p0119), [P0834](https://wg21.link/p0834), [P1170](https://wg21.link/p1170)).

Until then, the question of how to wrap invoking a particular member function on a type, where that member function is either overloaded or a template or takes default arguments, is pretty difficult.

The easiest way to do this is just to write a lambda:

```
[](A& a, auto&&... args) -> decltype(a.show(FWD(args)...)) { return a.show(FWD(args)...); }
```

But this is actually not that easy, nor is it particularly convenient - and it really only handles the case where `show` is invokable on a non-`const` `A`. What if we had `const` and non-`const` overloads? Or `&` and `&&`?

The most complete way to implement this, in my opinion, is to use [Boost.HOF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html) with [this macro](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2018/09/23/higher-order-fun/):

```
#define CLASS_MEMBER(T, mem) boost::hof::fix(boost::hof::first_of(\
    boost::hof::match(                                            \
        [](auto, T& s, auto&&... args)                            \
            BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(s.mem(FWD(args)...)),               \
        [](auto, T&& s, auto&&... args)                           \
            BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(std::move(s).mem(FWD(args)...)),    \
        [](auto, T const&& s, auto&&... args)                     \
            BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(std::move(s).mem(FWD(args)...)),    \
        [](auto, T const& s, auto&&... args)                      \
            BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(s.mem(FWD(args)...))),              \
    [](auto self, auto&& this_, auto&&... args)                   \
        BOOST_HOF_RETURNS(self(*FWD(this_), FWD(args)...))        \
    ))
```

which in your case, you want: `CLASS_MEMBER(A, show)`. That will give you a function object that you can properly invoke:

```
auto show_fn = CLASS_MEMBER(A, show);
show_fn(a, 1);       // ok, calls a.show(1)
show_fn(a, 1, 2);    // ok, calls a.show(1, 2)
show_fn(a, 1, 2, 3); // error, no matching call - but sfinae friendly
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a workaround for this problem, like embedding the input arguments types in member function template or something?

Use lambdas instead of an object and a member function pointer. E.g.:

```
struct A {
    constexpr int show(int a, int b) const noexcept {return a + b;}
    constexpr int show(int a) const noexcept {return a * 3;}
};

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
int show(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    constexpr A a;
    auto f = [&a](auto... args) { return a.show(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
    show(f, 1);
    show(f, 1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain your function using a more specific type for a member function:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
int show(T && obj, int(std::remove_reference_t<T>::*Fn)(int, int) const, Args&&... args)
{
    return (obj.*Fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This definition, however, might be too constrained depending on your use-cases, since now `Fn` parameter has to exactly match the `int(int, int) const` signature including possible cv and ref-qualifiers.

Comment: this actually makes it more complete and general

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    int show(T && obj, int(std::remove_reference_t<T>::*Fn)(Args...) const, Args&&... args)
    {
     return (obj.*Fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

then it works for all different cases